# Drawing Rectangle around Custom TextBox control

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, drawrectangle

I'm trying to create a custom TextBox control that will have two additional properties BorderColor and BorderSize. But the border doesn't shows up, even with BorderStyle set to None.
Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.ComponentModel


Public Class BorderedTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Dim BColor As Color = Color.Black
    Dim BSize As Double = 1.0

    Public Property BorderColor As Color
        Get
            Return BColor
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            BColor = value
        End Set
    End Property



    Public Property BorderSize As Double
        Get
            Return BSize
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            BSize = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics

        Dim pen As New Pen(BColor, BSize)
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size))
        pen.Dispose()

        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Location is relative to the form.  use e.ClipRectangle as the starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix, it worked, but the rectangle is removed when TextChanged event occurrs.

Comment: thats because with `ControlStyles.UserPaint` you have to handle **all** the painting not just the borders.

Comment: Damn! isn't there any alternate way to create a custom TextBox with colored borders?

Comment: you could build a UserControl which is 1-2-3 pixels larger than a textbox it contains, then let the UC Background be the "border"

Comment: Create a property then check this for a condition and handle the painting...

Comment: Another option is a Panel containing a TextBox.  Set the TextBox dock to Fill and change the Padding property of the Panel to set the border size.  The BackColor of the Panel is the border color.