# How to change DateTimePicker border color in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, border, datetimepicker, dotnetbar

Is there any easy way to change the border of DateTimePicker Control ? I want it to have a LightGray border to match my application theme. I also tried DateTimeInput control of DotNetBar, it has an option to change border color, but the DropDownButton in it has LightBlue theme. I have also tried adding an image to that button but it doesn't covers up whole button, the blue sides of the buttons are still visible.

Comment: same answer(s) as before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24590983/1070452

Comment: Which one? I guess there is neither Paint event for DateTimePicker nor there is BorderStyle to hide current border.

Comment: there are 2 or 3 workable options in the comments: host the control(s) on a UserControl or Panel which is a few pixels larger than the control and use **that** as a custom border

Comment: But what about the existing border? DateTimePicker already has a Gray 2.0 solid border, how can i hide that?

Comment: you could try using VisualStyles: stackoverflow.com/q/7132329/1070452 the DTP may be tricky because it is a drop down window does not exist until it opens